# What is the utility of the Transferwise debit card?

Tags: money-transfer, international-transfer

I can't get my head around what [the Transferwise debit card](https://transferwise.com/us/borderless/card) offers. If I have a credit card with no foreign fees, then I can just make payments with that wherever I go. Same with withdrawing cash using a debit card from a bank that doesn't charge fees (Transferwise only allows $250/month with no fees).

They do provide native banks account numbers for receiving money in each country, so that seems very interesting and novel, for people who have that specific need. But it's funny because the payment and cash withdrawal features seem very pedestrian, while the "bank account in every country" feature is super specialized and high powered for rare use cases.

As someone who very frequently travels and sometimes lives for several weeks or months abroad, I can't find a use for this card for myself, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the real-time currency conversion feature stated in the other answer, the debit card can be used to withdraw foreign currency directly from a foreign currency account of TransferWise borderless account.

This means that if you are from the US and are planning to go to Europe 6 months later, you can buy the EUR today, park it as the EUR account of Transferwise, then use your debit card 6 months later. This is a "lock-in" feature.

This feature (Withdrawing foreign cash from your foreign currency account) is popularized by Mastercard. Some banks are starting to offer this feature on their debit card.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your credit card has no foreign fees, you'll be paying money to exchange currency because of the *spread*.

For example, look at Visa's exchange rates using their [calculator](https://www.visa.co.uk/support/consumer/travel-support/exchange-rate-calculator.html).

If I'm spending dollars on a euro-based credit card, for today I'll get [1.128601 dollars for one euro](https://www.visa.co.uk/support/consumer/travel-support/exchange-rate-calculator.html?amount=1&fee=0.0&utcConvertedDate=&exchangedate=06%2F12%2F2020&fromCurr=EUR&toCurr=USD&submitButton=Calculate+exchange+rate).

But if I'm spending euros on a dollar-based card, for today I'll spend [1.140499 dollars to get one euro](https://www.visa.co.uk/support/consumer/travel-support/exchange-rate-calculator.html?amount=1&fee=0.0&utcConvertedDate=&exchangedate=06%2F12%2F2020&fromCurr=USD&toCurr=EUR&submitButton=Calculate+exchange+rate).

This difference (or half of it) is essentially an invisible cost you are paying to convert money between two currencies. You'll pay a much higher spread to exchange cash at supposedly "commission-free" foreign currency bureaus.

Transferwise and other "challenger" foreign exchange fintechs like Revolut advertise exchange rates with no spread at all, i.e. apart from rounding you buy and sell at exactly the same rate, and then they charge an explicit fee on top of that. In many, but not all cases that works out cheaper than paying the spread charged by Visa or other card providers.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. But, how do I fund the euros on my Transferwise card in the first place? Are you saying funding transferwise using USD, and paying their fee, will still cost me less than paying with a USD CC? Both the USD CC and Transferwise advertise that the exchange rate they give me is "what you find on google". But the CC has no fee.

Comment: You'd need to check for yourself what the actual rates are for what you want to do and then compare them. Transferwise is explicit that it uses mid-market rates. I think traditional credit cards generally get their rates from the network (Visa/Mastercard/Amex) but you would need to check that.

Comment: Yes, credit cards use mid-market rates. Is there a reason you think otherwise?

Comment: @JohnBachir the visa rates I quoted in my answer?

Comment: If your credit card really does give you the mid-market rate with no fee, then they are clearly a better deal than Transferwise. However, to the best of my knowledge that is very rare.

Comment: In the past I've spot-checked a few transactions with CapitalOne 360 banking debit, and also a CapitalOne credit card, and they seemed to be identical to what came up on google. If they were different, the difference was definitely much less than the TW fee. But maybe capitalone is an exception?

Comment: (and sorry, failed to click through on your answer before I wonder if it's different in the US where I am)

Comment: According to https://www.capitalone.com/support-center/bank/foreign-transaction-fee, CapitalOne use Mastercard, and when I check the Mastercard calculator at https://www.capitalone.com/support-center/bank/foreign-transaction-fee , I definitely see a spread. They'd have to be bypassing Mastercard and doing the conversion themselves (like Transferwise/Revolut) to avoid it.

Comment: data point: €162 purchase yesterday came up as $183.63 on my Uber Barclays Visa, for rate of 1.13352. Transferwise's rate about an hour later when I checked was 1.1267, so about half a percent cheaper. But, 1) they add their nontrivial fees 2) my CC gives me 1-3% cash back.